# SQL Query Including Joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have a database with two tables, profile, and friends. The primary key in profile is an auto incremented int, and it is a foreign key in friends. The fields in the profile table are: id, name, age, bio, motto, email_address.

The fields in friends is: initiator_id, receiver_id, date_added.

So ultimately I am trying to make a query where I set the initiator_id and get a list of receiver_id's, and use those id numbers to get them from the profile table.

I've tried left join's, inner joins, and joins in general. Open to suggestions, and interpretations on what these types of joins are actually doing.

```
select friends.receiver_id, profile.name 
from profile 
    inner join friends on friends.initiator_id=1;
```

I need the fields to return the receiver_id number as well as the corresponding name for that id number.

Answer (score 2):

The specification is a bit unclear. Sample data and expected output would go a longs ways towards illustrating the requirements.

But my guess (and without a specification, its just a guess) is that we are after the resultset returned from this query:

```
 SELECT f.receiver_id
      , p.name
   FROM friends f
   JOIN profile p
     ON p.id = f.receiver_id
  WHERE f.initiator_id = 1
```